# Sum of all partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Is there a name for the quantity

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$$

the sum of all partial derivatives of $f$?

Comment: I don't think so, but it is the derivative $Df(x)$ evaluated at the point $(1,...,1)^T$.

Comment: It is divergence $\vec{\nabla}.\vec{f}$

Comment: I guess divergence is defined for vector fields... It is rather the directional derivative of $f$ w.r.t. the direction $(1,1,\cdots,1)$.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam: Divergence is $\sum_i \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_i}$, which is not quite what's in this question.